# MySQL Database structure for a form with unknown number of values for one field

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a form that is, for the most part, very basic. The exception is that two of the fields are grouped together and I want my users to be able to create multiple values for those grouped fields. For example my form looks like this:

```
Your Name
Email Address
{Dog's Name
Dog's Breed}
```

The 2 dog fields are the fields that are related/grouped together. Below these 2 fields I will have a button that will ask the user if they want to add another dog. Upon clicking this button 2 brand new Dog's Name and Dog's Breed fields will appear.

My question is how should I structure my database for these values to go into? Is it best to have a submissions table that just hold's the person's name and email address - then - create a separate table that holds only dog names and breeds with an ID (foreign key) which would relate each dog to an entry in the submissions table?

**OR**

Is it somehow possible to have just one table (submissions) that has a column for Name, Email, Dog's Name, Dog's Breed but hold multiple values within Dog's Name and Dog's Breed field?

I hope I'm explaining this clearly haha :)

Comment: The first route, separate tables, is the correct way to comply with [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Answer (score 0):

Table 1: Users
Columns: id (auto increment), name, emailadress

Table 2: Dogs
Columns: id (auto increment), uid (=user_id), name, breed

On submit, check if users exists (can be done by checking the emailadress). If not, insert a user and remember the `last_insert_id()`
If user is present, select its id.

Now loop through your dogs array, inserting them in the dogs-table, with the $uid we just found

The reason you want seperate tables, is that you now can have an unlimited amount of dogs per person.

---

You could do even better ;)
table 3: dog_breeds
Columns: id (auto_increment), name

And now alter the 'breed' from the dogs-table to the id belonging to a breed. This way you can control the amount of breeds entered, and this might help prevent double names such us 'name' and 'Name' (which, to humans, are the same)